# Stop the scroll of listview dynamically

Tags: android, android-listview

When my listview is scrolling and then i touch somewhere else on my screen, the listview scrolling should stop. So is there a way to stop the vertical scroll of listView depending upon some condition?

I can disable the scroll before compiling and onTouch() i can return true to avoid scroll but i am not getting to stop it without touching it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done using reflection. Found this code somewhere.

```
try {
        Field field = android.widget.AbsListView.class.getDeclaredField("mFlingRunnable");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object flingRunnable = field.get(listView);
        if (flingRunnable != null) {
              Method method = Class.forName("android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable").getDeclaredMethod("endFling");
              method.setAccessible(true);
              method.invoke(flingRunnable);
           }
   } catch (Exception e) {}
```